# How to make this template code work?

Tags: c++, templates

the template code is like this:

```
template <class type1>
struct DefaultInstanceCreator {
    type1 * operator ()() {
        return new type1;
    }
};

template < class type1
, class InstanceCreator = DefaultInstanceCreator<type1> >
class objectCache 
{
    public:
        objectCache (InstanceCreator  & instCreator) 
          :instCreator_ (instCreator) {}
        type1* Get() {
            type1 * temp = instCreator_ ();
        }
    private:
        InstanceCreator instCreator_;
};
```

this code work well with object class like this:

```
class A{
public:
    A(int num){
        number = num;
    }
    int number;
    struct CreateInstance {
        CreateInstance (int value) : value_ (value) {}
        A * operator ()() const{
            return new A(value_);
        }
        int value_;
    };
};
objectCache< A, A::CreateInstance > intcache(A::CreateInstance(2));
    A* temp = intcache.Get();
    cout << temp->number <<endl;
```

when I tried this template with type like int, string...

```
objectCache< int > intcache();
int* temp = intcache.Get();
*temp = 3;
cout <<temp <<endl;
```

I get E left of "'.Get' must have class/struct/union", 
I can't find out where is the problem

when I change to

```
objectCache< int > intcache;
```

I get "'objectCache' : no appropriate default constructor available"

use

```
objectCache< int > intcache(DefaultInstanceCreator<int>());
```

I get left of "'.Get' must have class/struct/union" too.

Comment: added objectCache() {} to objectCache class make it work with objectCache< int > intcache;
now I understand more about template thanks for everyone's answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In here, you aren't passing in the parameter to the `intcache` constructor:

```
objectCache< int > intcache();
int* temp = intcache.Get();
```

This causes the first line to revert to the well known ["most vexing parse"](http://episteme.arstechnica.com/eve/forums/a/tpc/f/6330927813/m/5650981735) of C++, in short, you are declaring `intcache` as a function which takes no parameters and returns `objectCache<int>`.

Maybe you mean this:

```
objectCache< int > intcache;
```

But probably you wanted to pass a factory:

```
objectCache< int > intcache((DefaultInstanceCreator<int>()));
```

Comment: In the last line, you forgot parentheses around the constructor argument. I fixed that (weird - the questioner had this line in his question too, and wondered about the resulting error - why didn't he ask you?). I would like to mention too that the constructor of `objectCache` would needed to be changed not to accept by non-const reference, so it can accept the temporary.

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring a function, instead of a variable. Try this:

```
objectCache< int > intcache;
```

Answer (score 1):

Creating an object of objectCache seems wrong. It should be:

```
objectCache<int> intcache;
```